# Append the content of a file to the value of a variable in ksh

Tags: shell

Can we append the content of a file to the value of a variable in the Korn shell? How?

`/bin/ksh`:

```
$ B.11.31  Oct  1 2008 01:54:10 $
Version 11/16/88
blok.c $Date: 2008/08/20 12:15:51 $Revision: r11.31/1 PATCH_11.31 (PHCO_38683)
expand.c $Date: 2008/10/28 10:48:37 $Revision: r11.31/1 PATCH_11.31 (PHCO_38683)
builtin.c $Date: 2007/10/25 15:12:29 $Revision: r11.31/1 PATCH_11.31 (PHCO_37285)
test.c $Date: 2008/05/01 15:55:23 $Revision: r11.31/1 PATCH_11.31 (PHCO_38162)
strdata.c $Date: 2008/08/25 18:24:40 $Revision: r11.31/1 PATCH_11.31 (PHCO_38683)
$Revision: @(#) ksh88 R11.31_BL2009_0729_2 PATCH_11.31 PHCO_38683
```

**Desired Output**

```
user@hostname>echo $somevariable value_stored_in_variable
user@hostname>cat somefile value_stored_in_file
user@hostname>append operation
user@hostname>echo $somevariable
value_stored_in_variablevalue_stored_in_file
```

Comment: What do you mean by “append a file to a variable”? Do you want to append the content of a file to the value of a variable, e.g. if the variable `foo` contains `sometext` and the file `somefile` contains `somecontent` and you do this operation on the variable `foo` and the file `somefile`, then the file isn't modified and the variable ends up containing `somecontentsomefile`? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: foo contains sometext and the file somefile contains somecontent, so the variable foo should contain sometextsomecontent after appending the content of the file to the value of the variable

Comment: @user3146086 Update your question by editing it. Give the before and after situation clearly (just mark the part you don't know with a comment)

Answer (score 0):

```
myhost_2:home/myself $ cat /dev/null > Test3.txt
myhost_2:home/myself $ cat Test3.txt
myhost_2:home/myself $ pwd >> Test3.txt
myhost_2:home/myself $ cat Test3.txt
/home/myself
myhost_2:home/myself $ SOME_VARIABLE=abc
myhost_2:home/myself $ echo $SOME_VARIABLE
abc
myhost_2:home/myself $ SOME_VARIABLE=${SOME_VARIABLE}`cat Test3.txt`
myhost_2:home/myself $ echo $SOME_VARIABLE
abc/home/myself
```

But should be in quotes

```
echo "${stringvar}`cat ${CURRENT_PROJECT_SCRIPT_GREPPED}_grepped.txt`"
```